# Refresh table onclick with jquery in mvc

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, datepicker

I have a table in my View. I've added a datepicker in my View, which posts the two selected dates into my Controller (dateFrom and dateTo). I then compare the dates of my objects and pass them back to the View. The data passing is all good but I'm having trouble refreshing the table and showing the new data.

I've tried a few different things, but this is basically it looks like. This function is ran onclick of the datepicker button:

```
function Search() {
    $(".myTable").empty();
    var dateFrom = $("#dateFrom").val();
    var dateTo = $("#dateTo").val();

    $.ajax({
        url: "/myDirectory/myController",
        method: "POST",
        data: {
            dateFrom: dateFrom,
            dateTo: dateTo
        },
        success: function (asd123) {
            $(".myTable").show();
        }
    })
}
```

This function, though, just empties the data and doesn't show the new one. What should I be looking at here?

Comment: You have not bind you return data to your table $(".myTable"); it should be  $(".myTable").html(asd123);

Comment: Hmm, how do you mean? In my view I iterate through my objects and add them to my table. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Updated your code check below ans.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create separate Partial View for table content so that you can refresh that content through Ajax call follow below process for that :

**Your main view Ajax Call should be :**

```
function Search() {
$(".myTable").empty();
    var dateFrom = $("#dateFrom").val();
    var dateTo = $("#dateTo").val();
$.ajax({
   url: "/myController/PartialViewAction",
   type: "POST",
   dataType: "html",
   data: {
            dateFrom: dateFrom,
            dateTo: dateTo
        },
   success: function (data) {
       $(".myTable").html(data);
       $(".myTable").show();
     
   }
});
}
```

**Main View :** Remove Table Content Div and add on partial view and add below instead of that

//Here is the code for call Partial view on main view

```
<div id="TableContent" Class="myTable">
    @Html.Partial("_PartialViewForTable", Model)
</div>
```

**Create Partial View With name of "_PartialViewForTable" and add Table Content of mail view**
//Do not call **Layout Page** on partial view

```
@model Application.Model.YourModel
<div id="TableData">
//Your Table Data 
</div>
```

**And Your Controller Action should be :**

//Action is returning partial view instead of main view

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult PartialViewAction(DateTime? dateFrom = null, DateTime? dateTo= null)
{
 YourModel objYourModel = new YourModel();
 //Bind data in objYourModel and retun to your view
 return PartialView("_PartialViewForTable", objYourModel);
}
```

Comment: thank you very much! this shows the data when i search. still weird, even though i followed your code example it renders the whole view inside my table... so i get double views. anything more i'm missing, which is causing the double views, even though i'm using partialviews?

Comment: oh. it renders the "whole view" because the header layout is re-rendered when i PartialView(myview, mymodel). is there any good fix to set Layout = null when it's "coming" from the PartialView call?

Comment: You need to make partial view of your table data and call that view on main page view. Try it if not done I will share you the code for it then it will work.

Comment: I have updated above code for make separate partial view and return to the main view this type of process you have to follow then this will work.

Comment: Let Me know if you are facing any problem other wise Mark this ans is accepted thanks.